# How to count the frequency of bundle of number using c#?

Tags: c#, frequency

Can somebody help me to run this program using c#.  This program is to calculate the frequency of the number, for example 12 appear 10x.  Before this I try to sort all list number in a horizontal line. Then I compare the same number, then count++,  but until know I can’t get the output.

Thanks for helping.

INPUT

46 31 46 9 25 12 45 33
25 12 12 12 28 36 38 28
25 12 12 9 36 38 36 36
12 9 36 12 12 25 28 34
36 36 9 12 16 25 28 44

OUTPUT

9 – 4
12 -10
16 – 1
25 – 5
28 - 4
31 – 1
33 – 1
34 - 1
36 – 7
38 – 2
44 – 1
45 – 1
46 – 2

Comment: Please provide some code, at least, and maybe the current output.

Comment: smells like homework....

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could do this manually using a `Dictionary<int, int>`:

```
var frequencies = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var item in data)
{
    int currentCount;
    // We don't care about the return value here, as if it's false that'll
    // leave currentCount as 0, which is what we want
    frequencies.TryGetValue(item, out currentCount);
    frequencies[item] = currentCount + 1;
}
```

A simpler but less efficient approach would be to use LINQ:

```
var frequencies = data.ToLookup(x => x) // Or use GroupBy. Equivalent here...
                      .Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                      .ToList();
foreach (var frequency in frequencies)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", frequency.Value, frequency.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of numbers:

```
var numbers = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
```

Then we can use Linq to achieve what you want:

```
var frequencies = 
    numbers.GroupBy( n => n ).Select( n => new { Value=n.Key, Count=n.Count() } );

foreach (var f in frequencies)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Value={0}, Frequency={1}", f.Value, f.Count));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary of int and int: Dictionary and iterate through the numbers adding 1 as you go. some solutions use an array, but I prefer a dictionary this eliminates the need to manage the size of the array and is more memory efficient.

```
int[] someValues = { /* your numbers */ }
Dictionary<int,int> Counts = new Dictionary<int,int>();
foreach(int key in someValues)
{
    if ( !Counts.HasKey(key) ) Counts[ key ] = 0;
    Counts[key] = Counts[key] + 1;
}
```

then, you just iterate over the dictionary for your output:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int,int> kvp in Counts)
{
    Console.Write("{0} - {1}",kvp.Key,kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: how about if the bundle of number is in combination of 2-itemset?? how to count it. for example..                                                  {1,2}
{1,3}
{1,4}
{2,1}
{2,3}
{2,4}
{3,1}
{4,1}
.....                                                                   itemset {1,4} and {4,1} is assumed same. so, the frequency is 2..

Comment: so you change your comparison to check item[0] and item[1]

Answer (score 1):

I would put them all into a list then use a group by clause to group them ie

```
        List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 4, 4 };
        foreach (var group in numbers.GroupBy(n => n))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was found {1} times", group.Key, group.Count());
        }
```

Comment: how about if the bundle of number is in combination of 2-itemset?? how to count it. for example..                                                  {1,2}
{1,3}
{1,4}
{2,1}
{2,3}
{2,4}
{3,1}
{4,1}
.....                                                                   itemset {1,4} and {4,1} is assumed same. so, the frequency is 2.. the output will be like this:                                         {1,2} – 2
{1,3} - 2
{1,4} - 2
{2,3} - 1
{2,4} - 1
help me...T_T                                                             tq for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Homework assignment? We're not here to do homework assignments for you, but I will give you advice on what to do.

First, I would have a text reader so your input can be inputted. Then, parse each entry and add it into a dictionary. Then, iterate thru the dictionary to see how many times a specific entry occurs.